# Identify Ajax request in a Umbraco page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, umbraco4

I use Umbraco 4.7.

I have a page of news - `NewsPage` with 3 functionalities:

a) display the list of news (3 max on first page, module `NewsList.cshtml`),
b) "display detail of a news" in a popup (template `Ajax\Popup.cshtml`), and
c) "display more news" (displays the next 3 news on the list).

As I don't know how to use 2 Ajax templates for the same page (one for popup and one for more news),
**I would like to use the same module (*NewsList*) to display "next 3 news".**

How, in the `NewsList.cshtml`, to make difference between a normal "get" and an "Ajax get"?

Answer (score 0):

In NewsList.cshtml, add this:

```
@{
var isAjax = Request.IsAjaxRequest(); 
}
```

Then you can use the "isAjax" variable in your Razor code to change the output.